# Working on sqlite 3 and Android

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sqlite example program in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721732/sqlite-example-program-in-android)

I've created an sqlite3 database and a number of tables using SQLiteManager 3.5.1. However, i've no idea as to how i should be able to connect, access and use the database. Moreover, i also want to be able to modify the tables and the data in the tables. Is it possible to put the database (with the .sqlite extension) within the assets directory and work back and forth from the android to SQLiteManager?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. Here it's explained:

[Using SQLite from your Android App](http://huuah.com/using-sqlite-from-your-android-app/)

Take a look at the *Copying from assets to database path* section.