# Where is my database file in android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I created project from this URL:
http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

but where is the database file (.db or .sqlite)?

Can anyone tell me the exact location?

Waiting for your response....

Answer (score 4):

The databases are stored in

```
/data/data/your.applications.package/databases
```

you can use the `adb shell` to that directory and open the db with `sqlite3`.

Answer (score 3):

Basically your database will be stored in this location

`data/data/your.project.packageName/databases`

Answer (score 2):

[image: show this]

in DDMS>> file explorer you can get db file

Comment: but i am not getting any file or folder in file explorer

Comment: if there is code problem are raise then also db file are not created over there, so first you have to check your code correctly and make  sure everything are gone same in tutorial

Comment: it is same. i have just copied the code. so no chance that anything goes wrong

Comment: apply some logic and check that code becase you have to some change from that code. and still get problem then this is not a problem of "view database file" so quit this discussion and accept my answer.

Comment: tame nikunj patel ne aolkho cho?

Comment: I know two nikunj patel about whom you are talking they both are in android development.

Comment: anyway problem is not yet solved. file explorer does not show any folder

Comment: click on DDMS then goto windows menu >> open showview>file explorer.

Comment: be yaar i can see file explorer but i am not able to see anything in it. now have you got my problem?

Comment: kadach mane lagyu ke tu file explorar pan joi na sakto ho, ok any way

Comment: this tutorial will frustrate to you i give you another one please try it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721732/sqlite-example-program-in-android
http://www.xoriant.com/blog/mobile-application-development/android-sqlite-database.html