# Need simple SQLite database example

Tags: android, sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sqlite example program in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721732/sqlite-example-program-in-android)

I need to open a database where I know the path/name, I need to read a known value, and write a value. I don't want to write 100 line "helper classes," I simply want to use the classes/functions that already exist. Can anybody provide a a simple example for this? It really shouldn't be more than a few lines of code.

1: Open database:

maybe this? openDatabase(String path, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int flags)

2: Execute SQL to display value (in a Toast perhaps)

3: Close database

Once I understand this basic functionality I will then worry about helper classes etc. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Fascinating that every single answer so far links to articles that do EXACTLY what I asked not to do. I just want a simple 3 line example of how to directly open a database and read from it.

Comment: you can learn android sqlite database tutorial from here. http://techlovejump.com/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A very good SQLite [tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html).

Comment: +1 - Just about to link to this one myself. :)

Answer (score 3):

Run through the [notepad tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex1.html)

Comment: your link is dead now