# How to view/pull/access to database file inside device

Tags: android, sqlite

I have installed my application on my device and would like to know how to pull the database off the device to view it.

Also how do I encrypt the database?

Comment: Try this...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721732/sqlite-example-program-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [DDMS](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html) to pull any file off of an emulator. If you are using a physical device you will need root access to get the database file off of the device because the data folder is protected.

I use [SQLite Database Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/) to view the database once I get the file off the device.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but I want to pull database from Physical Device I dont know how to get ROOT access of device

Comment: There is only one way to pull a database off of a physical device without root access, and that is using code inside the application that created it. Only the application that created the database can access the file location where it is stored.  This is because of Android's application sandbox security model.  You could place some code inside your application to move the database file to the SD card, but I would suggest installing the app on an emulator and use that to grab the database file.

Comment: OK, but can you help me how to get ROOT access of device

Comment: I have edited my last comment.  Rooting your device is off topic here on SO.  If you really really want to do that, please check Android Enthusiasts (http://android.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Ok, Thanks a lot for your precious suggestions...keep in touch